# c++ GLM multiply matrix with vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, glm-math, multiplication

I am trying to multiply a 4 by 3 matrix with a column vector of dimension 3 using c++ glm.

This is how it looks like:

```
glm::vec3 v3 = ...;
glm::mat4x3 mat = ...;
glm::vec4 result = mat * v3;
```

VS2012 shows me the following error at the '*' :

> IntelliSense: no operator "*" matches these operands
>
> operand types are: glm::mat4x3 * glm::vec3 ...

There is another error which showed up during compiling:

> error C2679: binary '*' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'glm::vec3' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

So what is the correct way to do this multiplication?

My answer:
Okay, so I know where is wrong already after more experiments. Basically, the key thing is that the way how glm defines matrix is different from our conventional way. `glm::mat4x3 mat` will actually create a 3 by 4 matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns. And if you access by `mat[i]` it will return you the ith column instead of the ith row.

Comment: That is an Intellisense error, not a compile error.  Are you getting compile errors?  Intelliisense is just a tool, it isn't the actual compiler.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a compile error as well. I have just edited my question.

Comment: According to the error, a `glm::vec3` can't be used as the right-side operand for that overloaded `*`.  Try `glm::vec4` instead of `glm::vec3`..

Comment: Thanks. It seems okay to have 'glm::vec4' on the right side, but then the return type becomes 'glm::vec3' which is not intended. Does that mean I have to extend the 'glm::mat4x3' to a 'glm::mat4'?